# What is the time complexity of this code for reversing words of a string?

Tags: python, time-complexity

```
input_string= "This is a string"
output=''
words=input_string.split(" ")
print(words)
for word in words:
    ts=''
    for l in range(len(word)-1,-1,-1):
        ts+=word[l]
    output+=ts + ' '

print(output)
```

I think the complexity o(n^2) but I am also confused between o(nm) complexity as for each word I then iterate over it's letters which is essentially a substring of length m

How to determine the correct complexity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to detect loops in the process (implicit and explicit) and their relative cardinality.

- `input_string.split(' ')` is going through the characters once, so O(n)
- The nesting of `for l in range(len(word)...` within `for word in words` will process each character no more than once, so it is also O(n)
- `output+=ts + ' '` is performed once per word but the nested loop does not include the spaces so the total number operations for the nested loops will still be less or equal to n

In short, the complexity is O(n).

But, when in doubt, timeit!.  You can experiment with various string lenghts and (using timeit) determine if the progression is indeed linear (i.e. time proportional to length of string)